# HTTP-request throws an exception FileNotFound

Tags: android

I have url: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/api/Account/Register` (ip:port). And in the browser I can get it like POST method without any problems. But Android throws an exception:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/api/Account/Register W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.contedevel.reserves.utils.RestApi.signUp(RestApi.java:37)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.contedevel.reserves.activity.RegisterActivity$UserRegistrationTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:415)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.contedevel.reserves.activity.RegisterActivity$UserRegistrationTask.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:396)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Wo9191rker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

**A request method is `POST` 100%.**

I create a new connection so:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Write arguments so:

```
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
final String body = builder.toString();
writer.write(body);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: This question might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379247/filenotfoundexception-while-getting-the-inputstream-object-from-httpurlconnectio. It seems to imply that your webserver is not responding. Are you sure you're using the correct url?

Comment: I didn't try to use `getErrorStream()`. Thank you! It can help really.

Comment: Yeah, `getErrorStream()` works perfectly! Thank you once yet!