# FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=

Tags: java, android, post, httpsurlconnection, google-geolocation

I am getting FileNotFoundException in Geolocation API. I have googled it and find that it support only POST method but I am already calling in POST itself.

Please find my code snip here below,

Activity:

```
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY";
LocationAsyncTask task = new LocationAsyncTask(this);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
else
    task.execute(url);
```

AsyncTask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
    HttpsConnectionHelper conn = new HttpsConnectionHelper(weakContext.get());
    String response = conn.httpPost(param[0]);
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "LocationAsyncTask = " + response);
    return null;
}
```

HttpsConnection:

```
String httpPost(String requestURL) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HttpsConnectionHelper# requestURL = " + requestURL);
    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HttpsConnectionHelper# url.openConnection()");

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.connect();

        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HttpsConnectionHelper# conn.connect()");

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HttpsConnectionHelper# is.available() = "+is.available());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }

        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "HttpsConnectionHelper#Exception# e.getMessage() = "+e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

**EDIT**

[Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview)

```
curl -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d \
'{ "homeMobileCountryCode":310,
   "homeMobileNetworkCode":410,
   "radioType":"gsm",
   "carrier":"Vodafone",
   "considerIp":true
}'
```

This is from official doc. I have written corresponding Android code using this Curl command.

```
public class GeolocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY";
    Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "GeolocationTask# doInBackground() apiUrl = " + apiUrl);
    String requestBody = "{ " +
            "\"homeMobileCountryCode\":310, " +
            "\"homeMobileNetworkCode\":410, " +
            "\"radioType\":\"gsm\", " +
            "\"carrier\":\"Vodafone\", " +
            "\"considerIp\":true " +
            "}";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set up the connection
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "GeolocationTask# doInBackground() before write");
        // Write the request body
        try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }

        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "GeolocationTask# doInBackground() after write");

        // Read the response
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "GeolocationTask# doInBackground() response.toString() = "+response.toString());
            return response.toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "GeolocationTask# doInBackground()# Excep = "+e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // Handle the result, e.g., parse the JSON response
    if (result != null) {
        // Parse and handle the JSON response here
        Log.d(MainActivity.LOG_TAG, "LocationAsyncTask(new) = " + result);
    }
}
```

}

But still getting same exception.

Comment: You are not posting anything. Instead you immediately try to read from an input stream.

Comment: @blackapps I am setting POST method here conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: ????? You are not posting. So what do you have in mind?

Comment: Yes you set the post method. I have seen that. But after that you are posting nothing.

Comment: Yes, but what I post. This is 3 years back project that time its working now Its giving me exception

Comment: Your code is just wrong. So sit down and repair.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated the code I am posting post parameter as per suggested in curl command. Please check edit section

Comment: Which statement causes the exception?

Comment: When trying to get inputstream from connection it just crashing. connection.getInputStream()

Comment: Is your app crashing? Why dont you catch that exception?

Comment: What is it that the server will sent?

Comment: I establish a connection and open input stream to read response. Then it is crashing. It seems problem with Url

Comment: What is it that the server will sent?

Comment: Is your app crashing? Why dont you catch that exception?

Comment: You have both a GET and a POST request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256681/discussion-between-amit-yadav-and-blackapps).

Comment: Please provide a complete stack trace

Comment: As I already explained when I make a connection to Url and get an input stream its crashing. Question title is stack message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of your exception is some kind of error that Geolocation API is returning you as a response. You need to check the response code before calling `getInputStream`, and process the error accordingly, something like the following:

```java
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode != 200) {
        // Get error response
        InputStream errorIs = connection.getErrorStream();
        processError(errorIs);
    } else {
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        // do whatever you want
    }
```

You can read [HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream--) Javadoc for details and get more ideas from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5379247/546117).

If you are trying to execute literally the same request that is given in the Geolocation API doc, then the error is caused by the wrong API key in the request parameters. Here is the result of running it on my machine:

```
C:\Users\evgenye>curl -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "homeMobileCountryCode":310, "homeMobileNetworkCode":410, "radioType":"gsm",    "carrier":"Vodafone",  "considerIp":true}'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "geolocation.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Eugene Evdokimov you are right problem with API_KEY when I read getErrorStream() I got message code=403 thank you very much.