# How to get HttpURLConnection error response code

Tags: java, android, http

When I look at SO the typical answer to my question is this:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)_urlConnection;
InputStream _is;
if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    _is = httpConn.getInputStream();
} else {
     /* error from server */
    _is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
}
```

From [Read error response body in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613307/read-error-response-body-in-java)

This seems quite reasonable, however when I look at the implementation of `HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` the very first thing it does is call `getInputStream()`. According to the documentation `getInputStream()` is supposed to throw an IOException if there was an error, hence the solution above will always throw an exception if the response code is not in the 200 range!

Have I missed something here? How am I supposed to get the response code if there is an error, if the very function that gives me the response code will throw in that case?

Here is what `getResponseCode()` in java.net.HttpURLConnection.java  looks like for me:

```
public int getResponseCode() throws IOException {
    // Call getInputStream() first since getHeaderField() doesn't return
    // exceptions
    getInputStream();
    String response = getHeaderField(0);
    if (response == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    response = response.trim();
    int mark = response.indexOf(" ") + 1;
    if (mark == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int last = mark + 3;
    if (last > response.length()) {
        last = response.length();
    }
    responseCode = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(mark, last));
    if (last + 1 <= response.length()) {
        responseMessage = response.substring(last + 1);
    }
    return responseCode;
}
```

Comment: Curious. When I look at it, the first thing it does is see whether `responseCode` is already set, and if so return it. The *next* thing it does is call `getInputStream()`, *in a `try` block*. I suggest you have another look.

Comment: Is it possible the android implementation is different from the general java one?

Comment: @Pragnani Yes, it does change. At present they are using their own implementation.

Comment: Full package name is java.net.HttpURLConnection (android-21)

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha - i gave you explanation

Comment: **See here for a real answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232931/1599699**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## that what you are showing is sun old implementation of

> public abstract class HttpURLConnection extends URLConnection

[image]

new HttpURLConnection implementation

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/huc/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java

```
@Override public final InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (!doInput) {
      throw new ProtocolException("This protocol does not support input");
    }

    HttpEngine response = getResponse();

    // if the requested file does not exist, throw an exception formerly the
    // Error page from the server was returned if the requested file was
    // text/html this has changed to return FileNotFoundException for all
    // file types
    if (getResponseCode() >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException(url.toString());
    }

    return response.getResponse().body().byteStream();
}

 /**
 * Returns an input stream from the server in the case of error such as the requested file (txt,
 * htm, html) is not found on the remote server.
 */
 @Override public final InputStream getErrorStream() {
  try {
  HttpEngine response = getResponse();
      if (HttpEngine.hasBody(response.getResponse())
          && response.getResponse().code() >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
        return response.getResponse().body().byteStream();
      }
      return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      return null;
    }
}
```

An HTTP & HTTP/2 client for Android and Java applications. For more information see the website and the wiki.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

ps. if u want read error steam stream:

```
/**
 *  from sun.misc.IOUtils class.
 *  It's nearly twice as fast as the common implementation using ByteBuffers:
 *  */
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream is, int length, boolean readAll) throws IOException {
    byte[] output = {};
    if (length == -1) length = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < length) {
        int bytesToRead;
        if (pos >= output.length) { // Only expand when there's no room
            bytesToRead = Math.min(length - pos, output.length + 1024);
            if (output.length < pos + bytesToRead) {
                output = Arrays.copyOf(output, pos + bytesToRead);
            }
        } else {
            bytesToRead = output.length - pos;
        }
        int cc = is.read(output, pos, bytesToRead);
        if (cc < 0) {
            if (readAll && length != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new EOFException("Detect premature EOF");
            } else {
                if (output.length != pos) {
                    output = Arrays.copyOf(output, pos);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        pos += cc;
    }
    return output;
}
```