# How to retrieve fault information from soap error response using script in SoapUI mock service

Tags: soap, groovy, mocking, soapui, fault

I created a mock service in SoapUI. I am using Groovy in this mock service so I can mock some requests, as well as forward other requests to the actual web service I am mocking. 
When the web service returns one of three possible fault messages, I am unable to retrieve that actual fault from the soap response.

The mock service Groovy script just replies with the response herebelow (IOException, http status 500). 
But when sending a request to the actual web service directly, I get the response I actually would like to get.

Groovy code which forwards the request and retrieve a response:

```
        def soapUrl = new URL("[actual web service]");
        def connection = soapUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type" ,"text/html");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
        connection.doOutput = true;

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.outputStream);
        writer.write(soapRequest);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        connection.connect();

        def soapResponse = connection.content.text;
        // alert.showInfoMessage(soapResponse);

        requestContext.responseMessage = soapResponse;
```

Response using the Groovy scripted mock service:

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Failed to dispatch using script; java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: [the endpoint url]</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response when accessing the web service directly (with the same request):

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring> [actual fault message] </faultstring>
         <detail> [useful details about the fault] </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When using the script, why is the response not the same as if I would retrieve it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out I can use the connection (URLConnection) in a different way. 
I made some changes based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613307/read-error-response-body-in-java).
Now, the actual response, happy or error, is retrieved. So in both cases the web service response is being forwarded to the mock service output. And now I can see the fault info in the response.

```
        ...
      connection.connect();

    // Get the response
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    InputStream is;
    if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
            is = httpConnection.getInputStream();
    } else {
        // Http error
            is = httpConnection.getErrorStream();
    }

    // Read from input stream
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
    buffer.close();

    // Forward the response to mock service output
    requestContext.responseMessage = builder.toString();
```