# Rest API can be called from Postman, shows 400 bad request from Java

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to consume a POST restful service. When I try it on Postman I get succesful response. But when I try it on java with below code I am gettin response code 400. In postman I am pasting the same input with replacing escape characters.

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("https://localhost/PasswordVault/api/Accounts");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\", \"detail\":{\"ver\":\"2020\",\"productionDate\":\"2020\"}}";

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();


    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:- " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Encode your request post data in UTF-8: `"post data".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`
- Read the response from the server (not just the code) to hopefully get more details on the problem (`connection.getErrorStream()`)
- Is there a missing authorization header? (an API token etc.)
- Use single quotes to make your request data string more readable, or use a JSON library to avoid manual mistakes
- also call OutputStream.close() after flush()

E.g.

```
  // handle error code
  if(connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    // use getErrorStream for non OK statuses (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613307/read-error-response-body-in-java)
    String errorMessage = "HTTP response code: " + responseCode
        + (responseMessage == null || responseMessage.trim().length() == 0 ? "" : " " + responseMessage);

    InputStream errorStream = connection.getErrorStream();
    if(errorStream != null) {
      String errorString = streamToString(connection.getErrorStream());
      if(errorString.length() > MAX_MSG_LENGTH) {
        errorString = errorString.substring(0, Math.min(MAX_MSG_LENGTH, errorString.length())) + "...";
      }
      errorMessage += ", HTTP response data: " + errorString;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage);
  }

  // handle OK code
  // ...
```

Comment: I am getting a token for autharization from another URL.TOken URL response is having extra quotes. So that was the problem. What a shame. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you use a library for this.
You can use Jackson, this greatly simplifies and standardizes java interaction with remote HTTP services.

Something along these lines will get you started:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class ApiClient
{

    private transient Client client;
    protected transient WebTarget apiRoot;

    public ApiClient(String rootUrl) 
    {
        this.client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        // The root URL is your API starting point, e.g. https://host/api
        this.apiRoot = client.target(rootUrl);
    }

    public Response doPostToAccounts(String data)
    {
        try 
        {
            // This is where you execute your POST request
            return apiRoot.path("/Accounts")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(data, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried your solution. I got "Server redirected too many times(20)" error. Than I searched it and I found adding ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false may have been resolve the problem but this time I am getting 301- Moved Permanently

Comment: Did you pass `https://localhost/PasswordVault/api` as the rootUrl and `/Accounts` as the path? Typically 301 means it expects a / at the end. Also: the `Response` object will contain information about where it redirects you to.

Comment: Thank you for your caveat. As you mentioned, I copied url wrongly. After correction I am getting 400 Bad request again. I tried 3 different methods for calling the service. And getting same 400 response. I am pretty sure that there is something dfferent from the postman request. I will add what is extra in postman's header to my request.

Comment: Keep in mind that a HTTP 400 error often means: the request body is not correct for the resource, or the content type is incorrect for the body.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the request headers that the postman may be sending and your code does not. You may need to add some headers to your request before sending it. Second, I strongly recommend to use some 3d party Http client library instead of coding your HTTP request on your own. Some well known libraries are [Apache Http client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) and [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/). I personally use my own Http client that is part of a MgntUtils Open source library. You are welcome to try it as well. Here is simplified code just to demonstrate reading some response from a site:

```
    try {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.setConnectionUrl("https://www.yahoo.com/");
        String result = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, "com.mgnt."));
    }
```

But of course you could send POST requests and set Request headers and read textual or binaly response and response headers with this library as well. Here is a link to [HttpClient class Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The library itself is available as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases), including Javadoc and source code

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried with Apache HttpClien as you adviced. But I am still getting 400 Bad request response.

Comment: So, check the response headers, you may find the reason why you get the error

Comment: Also, if you use my library, it automatically retrieves errorStream if an error code returns. So you may get some more additional info without extra-coding